# sIFR 3+li menu

Tags: sifr

I'm trying to make a li-menu that use sIFR. What I wanna do is to make sIFR replace the first level of the menu but not the second level. The menu is only in two levels.

You can find the menu at: [www.norrlandsoperan.se/default.asp?id=10135](http://www.norrlandsoperan.se/default.asp?id=10135)

I would really appreciate if you could make me a hint on how to make this work.

Many thanks.

Regards / Erik Wennberg

Answer (score 1):

If the sub menu is contained within the parent `<li>`, you need to wrap the text in the parent `<li>` in a `<span>` element. Then use a selector like `ul#menu > li > span` to replace just those elements.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a selector like `ul#menu > li` to only get the first level of `<li>`s. I think that should work with sIFRs own selector engine, otherwise use jQuery (you can find in the sIFR documentation how to change it.)